# Error with simple shell script

Tags: shell

I wrote a shell script which automatically set up environment

```
#!/bin/sh

set path=(/dv/project/ $path)
```

I change the execution bit by

```
chmod +x init.sh
```

When I run it as

```
./init.sh
```

It prompted me with error

```
./init.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./init.sh: line 3: `set path=(/dv/project/ $path)'
```

What could be the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: `set path=`? What kind of syntax is that? What is it supposed to do? Where did you see documentation that made you think it's valid?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `set` is a valid command, as I know. It's used for setting up an environment options.

Comment: @denysdovhan, it's used for setting **flags** and modifying the list of command-line arguments. The OP is doing neither. `set -- path=foo` would be valid (setting `$1` to `"path=foo"`), but that's not what was given.

Comment: BTW, `#!/bin/sh` means your shell is POSIX sh, which has no array support.

Comment: When I run this command directly from terminal, it works. When I put in a shell script, it just gave me error.

Comment: @YifanHao is there any reason not to use `bash`?

Comment: I tried bash, but it didn't have any effect either.

Answer (score 0):

If using of `set` isn't required, just try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=(/dv/project/ $path)
```

As I have noticed, you're trying to extend your `$PATH` environment variable, right? There is a better way. Try [this approach](https://github.com/denysdovhan/dotfiles/blob/master/tilde/zshrc.zsh#L16-L26):

```
# Extend $PATH without duplicates
function _extend_path() {
  if ! $( echo "$PATH" | tr ":" "\n" | grep -qx "$1" ) ; then
    PATH="$1:$PATH"
  fi
}

# Add custom bin to $PATH
[ -d ~/.bin ] && _extend_path "$HOME/.bin"
```

Comment: That's much less efficient than need be. `_extend_path() { [[ $PATH =~ (^|:)"$1"(:|$) ]] || PATH+=":$1"; }` -- one compound command, no subshells.

Comment: Also, `path=( /dv/project/ $path )` is array syntax, which isn't valid with `/bin/sh` at all. Presumably you want `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Also, the `function` keyword isn't part of the POSIX sh standard, so that's a portability bug too; in POSIX sh, it's just `extend_path() {` with no `function` preceding to define a function. While I'm usually fond of bash extensions (when used with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang), this one adds no value over the portable alternative.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to extend the variable. I'm running in a company server and I can't modify those scripts which would be executed when I connect to the server. The first method doesn't work either. It won't give me any error, but it doesn't have any effect. As for the second method, could you explain what I need to change?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right. That makes sense.